# How to fetch admin profile details of a company page using Company API - Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

Is there a way to fetch Admin profile details/Company page owner details using Companies API?
or Vice-versa, to fetch Company Pages the user owns (Not his employers) using Profile API?

I read the documentation and could find a way for it, any help is highly appreciated.

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [LinkedIn API docs](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields) (last example in the Overview section), you can get all the companies a use is an admin for with the following call:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?is-company-admin=true
```

Comment: Just and additional note: no special permissions are require. The minimal permission `r_basicprofile` is sufficient.

Comment: It appears that this query is limited to 10 companies.  Do you know if there are pagination parameters?  The docs do not specify any.

Comment: This route returns 404 now in 2022. Is there another alternative to this?