# LinkedIn REST API - Accessing a list of companies the user can post to

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

How can I get a list of company pages that the currently authenticated user has permission to post to?

I have a user that has already been authenticated and authorized in my application but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the company pages he can post to, so that he can share updates to his pages from within my application.

I am not interested in which companies the user worked for, just the company pages he can post to.

I can see in the docs how to post to a company page *after* I get its ID but my problem is *getting* the ID.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is usual in these things, after hours of searching and ending up posting a question on SO, I found the answer - and in another SO question: [How to fetch admin profile details of a company page using Company API - Linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269729/how-to-fetch-admin-profile-details-of-a-company-page-using-company-api-linkedi)

A list of all the companies the user is admin for can be obtained here: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?is-company-admin=true

This is actually mentioned in the API docs but I didn't pay much attention to that page because I assumed it was all dealing with getting information about pages for which you already had the ID. Assumption - still the mother of all f$%& ups.

Comment: This endpoint doesn't seem to be working for me anymore. Does it work for you guys?